# How to bind a color from Settings to animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have defined some theme colors (`System.Windows.Media.Colors`) in the Properties.Settings file and want to be able to bind them to some animations.  However its not apparent to me how to do this.  I have no problem creating a SolidColorBrush like so.

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeSolidColorBrushPaleGray" 
    Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource settingsProvider}, 
    Path=Default.ThemeColorPaleGray}"/>
```

I can bind to a color defined in XAML

```
<Color x:Key="PaleGray2Color">#FF808080</Color> 
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"                                                 
                  To="{StaticResource PaleGray2Color}" 
                        Duration="00:00:02.00"/>
```

But the following fails at runtime

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"                                                 
     To="{Binding Source={StaticResource settingsProvider}, 
        Path=Default.ThemeColorPaleGray}" 
             Duration="00:00:02.00"/>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

could you rewrite your xaml and try one in following way:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"               Duration="00:00:02.00"                                   
     To="{Binding Source={StaticResource settingsProvider}, 
        Path=Color}"/>
```